# on jquery liberary jquery-1.4.2.min.js i want to show hide on hover of image but its not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

am i doing any silly mistake in this ? i tried closest and next but its not supporting in this liberary. and i cant change liberay as well. 
i want the function generaic so that i can use this icon multiple times

```
 <span style="position:relative" class="iconblock">
                <img class="queicon" src="images/question_icon.gif"  alt="icon" /> 
                <span class="helpPopup hidden">test test test</span>
```

```
$(".iconblock").mouseover(function() 
{
var sachin =  $(this).find("hidden");   
alert(sachin);  
});
```

Comment: oops sorrry i forgot .. lol .done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).find(".hidden");
```

You forgot `.` before hidden.

You can use a short cut too specifying the context  `$(".hidden",this)`

```
$(".iconblock").mouseover(function() 
{
  $(".hidden",this).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cJbVY/

If your intend is to show and hide on mouseover/mouse out you can try this

http://jsfiddle.net/ze6Xy/

```
$(".iconblock").hover(function() 
{
  $(".helpPopup",this).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that second syntax. `.find()`'s intent is much clearer and it's easier to read.

Comment: its not working anywys can you add fildde with the library jquery 1.4.2

Comment: Updated the answer and in the fiddle i am using 1.4.2

Comment: @Blender i agree but in cases where there are chain of selectors i always like using the root container as context and that helps me make it more readable. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to help here, Do you really need to use JS/Jquery, for this?

HTML:

```
<span style="position:relative" class="iconblock">
   <img class="queicon" src="images/question_icon.gif"  alt="icon" />
   <span class="helpPopup hidden">test test test</span>
```

And in CSS, something like:

```
.iconblock .hidden {
     display:none;
 }

.iconblock:hover .hidden {
     display:block;
 }
```

Comment: SHouldn't that be .iconblock .hidden and .iconblock:hover .hidden, it seems like he wants to hide and show the text on hover.